# Automatically draw a graph with a cycle in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I know how to automatically draw graphs with nodes being only bound to the next node in a "line". But how would I do it if I have a cycle like this:[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try graph drawing library?

Comment: no, what is this?

Comment: It's another library of TikZ. Check in the manual

Comment: PGF/TikZ has `cycle` (IIRC) in place of last node in path.

Comment: What kind of method have you used for nodes in a line? Of course, if you have three nodes `a`, `b` and `c` you can use `\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (a);`, but you were talking about "automatically", so I'm guessing you've used something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you intend a `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash},
row sep = 10pt] 
&&d\ar[dddd]\\
&b\ar[ur]\\
a\ar[dr]\ar[ur]\\
&c\ar[dr]\\
&&e\\
\end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your nodes are not math nodes you could use `\text{...}` from `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}, row sep = 10pt] 
&&\text{d}\ar[dddd]\\ 
&\text{b}\ar[ur]\\ 
\text{a}\ar[dr]\ar[ur]\\ 
&\text{c}\ar[dr]\\ 
&&\text{e}\\ 
\end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

or, if your texts are more complicated that a simple letter, a `tikz matrix` directly:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[row sep = 10pt,
column sep=20pt,
matrix of nodes] (m) {
&&d\\ 
&b\\ 
a\\ 
&c\\ 
&&e\\
};
\draw (m-1-3) -- (m-2-2) -- (m-3-1) -- (m-4-2) -- (m-5-3) -- (m-1-3);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

or without any matrix:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10pt and 20pt]
\node (d) {d};
\node[below left = of d] (b) {b};
\node[below left = of b] (a) {a};
\node[below right = of a] (c) {c}; 
\node[below right = of c] (e) {e};
\draw (a) -- (b) -- (d) -- (e) -- (c) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

(The result is the same as before).

Answer (score 2):

Alternately to `tikz-cd`, you can use this code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {$a$} node (b) at (2,1) {$p$} node (c) at (2,-1) {$d$};
\draw (a) -- (b);
\draw (a) -- (c);
\draw (b) -- (c);
\node[fill=white,text=black] at (1,0.5) {$e$} ;
\node[fill=white,text=black] (v1) at (1,-0.5) {$f$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```